# jQuery: getScript for including Javascript into Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the topic of "including a javascript file into another javascript file" has been discussed a lot. But my scenario is slightly different so I could not find an answer fitting to my problem.

Let's assume there are three files: test.html, starter.js and object.js

test.html simply includes starter.js using jQuery:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/starter.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.getScript("js/starter.js", loadobject());
        alert( "a" );
    });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

starter.js contains a function with `$.getScript` to include object.js and looks like this:

```
function loadobject() {
    alert( "b" );
    $.getScript("object.js", function(){
    Object.init();
    alert( "c" );
    });
}
```

Finally the object.js contains an object like the following:

```
var Object = {
init: function () {
            // . . .
},
searchString: function (data) {
            // . . .
    }
};
Object.init();
```

As far as I can see, when test.html is called in a browser it should include starter.js as soon as the document is ready. Furthermore, starter.js should load object.js when called.
But this seems to fail as the line `alert( "object loaded" );` is never executed.
I also trial-and-errored a lot, for example replacing the line in starter.js `$.getScript("object.js", function(){` with `$.getScript("object.js", init(){`, but I was not able to find a solution - although it might be simple. :(

How can I fix this and include the js file containing an object correctly?
Additionally how can a new `Object` be initialized and accessed within starter.js?

I think that I messed up with the `function()`, but actually I have no clue about that and appreciate any hint.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it intentional that you're including `starter.js` twice? Once through HTML `script` tag, once through `getScript()`. What is your goal with doing all this stuff? I don't see the point.

Comment: If I leave out the `script` tag, the `getScript()` function throws an error saying that the variable `loadobject` is undefined. With the `script` tag this error does not occur.

Comment: In this case you do not need the `getScript()`. Simply do `loadobject()` instead of `$.getScript("js/starter.js", loadobject());`. At that time, starter.js is already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works if you write it as follows,

**HTML**

*no need to load starter.js since you accomplish that by the getScript function*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="js/starter.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getScript("js/starter.js", function(){
                    alert('starter loaded');
                    loadobject();
                });
                alert("a");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**object.js**

```
var theObject = {
    init: function() {
alert('init');
    },
    searchString: function(data) {

    }
};
```

**starter.js**

*Specify absolute path and within the callback function you have access to the object as you assumed. Renamed Object to theObject since calling function on Object causes a jquery error to be thrown.*

```
function loadobject() {
    alert( "b" );
    $.getScript("/test/js/object.js", function(){
    theObject.init();
    alert( "c" );
    });
}
```

The result that you get is consecutive alerts showing
 "a" > "starter loaded" > "b" > "init" > "c"

Comment: Thank you for your detailled answer! I modified everything just the way you advised. Unfortunately the alerts only show "a" > "starter loaded" > "b". That's it. So I thought the path to object.js might be wrong but I tried the absolute path `/var/www/js/object.js` as well as the webserver path `http://serverip/js/object.js` and `httP://localhost/js/object.js` - it's always the same. There is no "init" and no "c" alert. At least Dragonfly does not show any errors ;-D

Comment: @coroner the code posted has been tested in chrome(30.0.x), ff(24) and opera (12.00)

Comment: Allright! That's working. Thank you very much! :) For some reason it did not work correctly on my localhost. When copied to a real-world webserver, everything's fine. Thank for your help and testing!

Answer (score 0):

pass the function reference and not  the function's returned value. you are calling the function there `loadobject()` and passing the returned value to it .

```
  $.getScript("js/starter.js", loadobject);
```

or

```
 $.getScript("js/starter.js", function(){
     loadobject()
 });
```

Comment: Actually he did not pass the function itself, but called it and tried to pass the return value.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand. When I leave out the brackets after `loadobject` in the `getScript` within test.html the function `loadobject()` of starter.js is not called. I added an `alert`-popup to the `loadobject()` function before the `getScript` function to verify this.
After all the object.js does not seem to be loaded, so the Object's `init` function is not executed.

Comment: I edited the code above so that you can see the added alerts. When using `loadobject()` in `getScript`, the alerts "b" and "a" show. When leaving these brackets out, only the "a" alert pops up. The alert "c" is never seen although there are no script errors in Dragonfly.